# define argument list for function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but i really don't actually know how to even ask this question. I'm coming from a native language background where you have control of how parameters are pass (by value, reference or pointer), and even though i've been using javascript for many years, i still have a tough time with knowing when variables are being passed by reference or value sometimes.

I'm would like to allow a function to be overridden in a javascript class, but basically i'm having a problem passing the arguments as a reference to the function.

I'll have to provide an example because i don't know exactly how to explain this.

So i have a "class", i'll call it exampleClass:

```
exampleClass = function()
{
    var m_largearray = [];
    var m_width = 100;
    var m_funcParams = {data: m_largearray, width:m_width};
    var m_someFunction = function(_params){
        // do stuff
    }
    var m_finalValues = [];
    return {
        doProcessing: function()
        {
            // do some things
            m_finalValues = m_someFunction(m_funcParams);
            // do stuff with the m_finalValues
        }
        setFunction: function(_func, _params)
        {
            m_someFunction = _func;
            m_funcParams = _params;
        },
        largearray: m_largearray,
        width: m_width
    }
}
```

So this class has a function which gets called, doProcessing(). Inside this function, it calls another function that does part of the processing, but i would like to have control of this part of the processing outside the class when i do not want the default way to process the data.

So something like this:

```
var classinstance = exampleClass();
var somespecialarray = [];
var someint = 5;
var somewidth = 900;
classinstance.setFunction(function(_params){
    // do some processing with different set of params
    // even though somewidth was set to 400, i will still get _params.width = 900 here
    // return some array
},
{data:somespecialarray, anint:someint, width:somewidth});
somewidth = 400;
classinstance.doProcessing();
```

This is just a complete example of what i'm trying to do, i just wrote this code here off the top of my head so if theres errors thats why.

Anyway, the problem with this is that the parameter list i set (i've tried using an array instead of an object). When i set m_funcParams, it seems the data is copied rather than referenced. When i change these arguments, m_largearray for example, when the default function gets called, the parameter data is what it was when i originally set m_funcParams, and not what i have updated m_largearray to be, the same as when i override the function, if i change somewidth from 900 to 800, when i call the function, the width parameter i still 900.

I hope this makes sense, i just need some clarity on why the function is not getting the updated values, and if there is a better way of doing this.

So, why is the function not getting the changed values, and is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
Here is a complete working example. I think i just realized when i set the variable to be something else, i'm basically losing a "pointer" to the value it was before. if i set an element in an array, it updates in the function, but if i set the whole array, it does not

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var exampleClass = function()
{
    var m_largearray = [1,2,3];
    var m_width = 100;
    var m_funcParams = {data: m_largearray, width:m_width};
    var m_someFunction = function(_params){
        // do stuff
        alert(_params.data[0]);
    }
    var m_finalValues = [];
    return {
        doProcessing: function()
        {
            // do some things
            m_finalValues = m_someFunction(m_funcParams);
            // do stuff with the m_finalValues
        },
        setFunction: function(_func, _params)
        {
            m_someFunction = _func;
            m_funcParams = _params;
        },
        largearray: m_largearray,
        width: m_width
    }
}

var classinstance = exampleClass();
classinstance.largearray[0] = 3;
classinstance.doProcessing();

classinstance.largearray = [7,8,9];
classinstance.doProcessing();

var somespecialarray = [4,5,6];
var someint = 5;
var somewidth = 900;
classinstance.setFunction(function(_params){
    // do some processing with different set of params
    // even though somewidth was set to 400, i will still get _params.width = 900 here
    alert(_params.width);
    // return some array
},
{data:somespecialarray, anint:someint, width:somewidth});
somewidth = 400;
classinstance.doProcessing();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is **always** pass-by-value. It gets confusing because when a value is an object, it's really a *reference* to the object. The term "pass-by-reference" however involves the word "reference" but with a precise meaning that's not the same as what we mean when we talk  about JavaScript object references.

Comment: can you provide working sample?

Comment: alright give me a second and i'll change the code to be a working example.

Comment: There's a good Snook article on this with simple examples: [JavaScript: Passing by Value or by Reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Comment: @Pointy, so to be clear, when you pass an object, your basically passing a "pointer" to the object, which is still basically pass by reference though isn't it? I think i've figured this out though, when i "re" set a variable that i had passed as a parameter, i'm actually creating a new variable and reusing that name. I was hoping there was a way to just set the value of that variable without losing the link between what i had passed as a parameter and the variable i'm setting

Comment: Yes - when a variable has an object as its value, the *real* value is in fact a *reference*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly and that this helps.

First of all when you pass an object to a function it passes as a reference, so changing one of it's properties will change the referred object's property.

However, when you invoked `classinstance.setFunction` in your example, you passed an object with a property `width` which recieved the variable `somewidth`, which is not an object so it gets passed by value.

Finally, when you changed `someWidth` to 800 you only changed `someWidth`, because `width` was passed as a value.

Edit:
In addition, when invoking `classinstance.setFunction`, you passed a function with param `_param` which is not part of that scope.

Comment: This is basically the conclusion i just came to when i created a working example above, thanks

Comment: please check my addition edit, I think there's another problem with your code

Comment: i don't know what you mean by your edit in addition. its just a parameter list, not an argument.

Comment: `setFunction` takes two params - _func & _params. You can't use the second param in the first, they don't share the same scope

Comment: but to solve this issue, i've figured what needs to happen is the argument needs to be an object, and when you change a variable, you'll have to change the object's variables, not the actual object you originally passed in. is this correct?

Comment: the first parameter to setFunction is a function, which i happen to give the first parameter the same name _params, the second parameter in setFunction is the parameter list i would like to pass to the function i'm setting